# My Saturn LW200 (2.2L) 2002 shows a error code P0719, does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

Tags: saturn

My Saturn LW200(2.2L) of year 2002 shows an error code P0179,
I do not know much about the error code and how to fix it so please help me of how can i fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

There is a switch just behind your brake pedal. It controls the clutch inside the torque converter. Generally the code is thrown because there is a short in the circuit. The conditions usually indicate to the computer that the voltage is incorrect or that the speed at which the vehicle is driving doesn't match the data the switch SHOULD be sending to it.

Basically you have a torque converter with an impeller and turbine inside of it. When you're going down the highway, the ECM essentially tells the clutch inside the torque converter to lock itself to the shaft to create a 1:1 gear ratio, which is great for higher speed driving. However this is not good if it's stuck like that. Which is most likely what will happen. it will cause the torque converter to heat up due to the stresses of lower speed driving. It would be equivalent to riding the clutch constantly rather than shifting and clutching. 
When the brake is depressed the clutch disengages or variate depending the position of the pedal.

The P0719 usually means the ECM is having an issue or there is an open or short in the circuit somewhere. The only way to fix that is to do a little electrical diagnosis and see if you can trace down where exactly there is an issue.

That being said, there are many designs so i can't tell you exactly how yours works, but what I can tell you is that you can damage the transmission by driving it too much. It's meant to be used for cruising purposes mostly with little load on the drive-train. If it never gets the signal to disengage it's always going to be on. Which isn't good.

That's the best advice I can give you for now. If you're not too savvy with electrical diagnostics, you might want to take it to someone. Automatic transmissions are a little complicated in their own right and are easy to screw up.